# Reproduce QGIS vector heat-maps via kernel density rasters

Tags: pyqgis, heat-map

I would like to reproduce the vector heat-maps generated through the user interface but via the pyqgis heat-map kernel density tool instead. Does anyone know the equivalent parameters? or styling code? After manually styling the resulting raster with the same color gradients & transparencies results differ..

### Desired Style

Note that this makes use of the `maximum value = 1` symbology setting.

[image]

### Programatically Invoked

```py
import processing as qgis_proc
raster = qgis_proc.run(
   "qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation",
   parameters={
      'INPUT': 'path/to/vector_points.shp',
      'OUTPUT': 'path/to/raster_heatmap.tiff',
      'RADIUS': 300,      # [m] consistent for both
      'PIXEL_SIZE': 10,
      'KERNEL': 3,        # triweight?
      'DECAY': 0,         # relevant?
      'OUTPUT_VALUE': 1,  # scale?
   }
).get('OUTPUT')

# styling code?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rasters generated via the `qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation` tool are fine. Just needed to style the sudo color band with **quantile color** distribution & save this layer's styling as a `<my_layer>.qml` file for future rendering.

[image]